# Godaddy domain pointing to AWS EC2 instance VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, hosting

I have a domain registered at godaddy but want to have webhosting at AWS Amazon. As per the instructions, updated the 'A' record with Elastic IP of AWS. But the website is down and not able to connect. Thanks in advance for any help. Am I missing anything on AWS EC2 VPC? I am not using Route 53 since this is not required as per AWS documentation.

Comment: What are the security group configurations on your EC2 instance? and what is the message you are getting when you try to access website?

Comment: Double check your inbound rules in your security. Make sure you have allowed http and/or https

Comment: The message from the browser - This site can’t be reached. ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Added http and https to inbound rules. still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

please check your application should hosted in port 80. Can you able to access your application IP:80 from browser..?

Comment: I can see the website with port 8080 but not with port 80. Is this the issue? How do I set up for port 80?

Comment: yes. that will be the reason. if you are using apache tomcat as a web server, just change connector port= 80 instead of 8080 in server.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the port you are running your application on. If your domain name is somexyz.com and your port is other than 80 (standard TCP port for HTTP service) like 5000 for default Flask werkzeug dev server, you will have to type somexyz.com:5000 on the browser to access your website. Otherwise run it on 80. The stackoverflow discussion here- [create a domain name pointing to an IP of port different than 80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25971399/create-a-domain-name-pointing-to-an-ip-of-port-different-than-80) should help.

(Also, this may be irrelevant now but the TTL field~600secs etc on godaddy reflects avg time for DNS records to get updated when we edit zone info 'A' field to point to Amazon Ec2 Elastic IP. So waiting for upto an hour or so helps.)