# VirtualHosts Not Working for Locally Hosted Apache Web Server

Tags: apache, macos-sierra, vhosts

I have an apache web server setup on my development machine (macos sierra). The configuration I had setup has been working fine for months, but for some reason it decided to stop working today. I have to include the port number (i.e. mysite.local.com:8080) for any locally hosted site I want to navigate to. If I leave off the port number I get ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE in the browser. The config test is passing with no errors. I haven't upgraded or changed anything on this machine (that I can recall) that would cause virtual hosts to stop working. Can anyone suggest a way to pin down what the issue is here?

FYI

**sudo apachectl -S** produces

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:87                   bto.local.tura.com (/private/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/bto.local.tura.com.conf:2)
*:8080                 is a NameVirtualHost
         default server mr.local.tura.com (/private/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mr.local.tura.com.conf:1)
         port 8080 namevhost mr.local.tura.com (/private/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mr.local.tura.com.conf:1)
         port 8080 namevhost optics.local.tura.com (/private/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/optics.local.tura.com.conf:1)
*:85                   overstock.local.tura.com (/private/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/overstock.local.tura.com.conf:1)
*:86                   static.local.tura.com (/private/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/static.local.tura.com.conf:1)
```

My httpd.conf:

```
Listen 8080
Listen 85
Listen 86
Listen 87

...
ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
...
Include /private/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/*.conf
```

An example of a vhhost config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:85>
ServerName overstock.local.tura.com
DocumentRoot /usr/local/web/overstock
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/overstock.local.tura.com.error.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/overstock.local.tura.com.access.log "combined"

<Directory "/usr/local/web/overstock">
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from all
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
</Directory>

LogLevel emerg
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Why would you expect it to work w/o a port in the URL if you don't listen on the ports? Just because you think it used to?  Why would an antivirus listen on a webserver port?  None of this adds up.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but I'm wondering if this is a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25971399/create-a-domain-name-pointing-to-an-ip-of-port-different-than-80

Comment: @ covener I don't know why sophos uses port 80 to communicate, but it does. Since this is a work machine, I really don't have a lot of choice in the matter, I simply have to work around it.

Comment: @pbuchheit, first of all your apache config doesn't listen on port 80, so I am not sure how it used to work earlier without specifying the port number, until unless you were using https. But you don't have a port 443 also listening, which means you were not listening on HTTPS to. So there are only thing possible here, either something has changed, or it didn't work earlier and it doesn't work now also without a port.

Answer (score -2):

I think you should add

```
Listen 80
```

Comment: I can't use port 80. It is currently being used by the anti-virus software on this machine. Hence the listener for 8080 instead.

Answer (score -2):

try by changing `deny from none` in place of `deny from all`

Answer (score -2):

what are errors from /var/log/apache2/error.log ,paste the content of error.log